# Coin flipping probability -- GRE question

Tags: probability, gre-exam

This question appeared on my GRE practice test, and I am wondering if there is a good general strategy for questions like this:

> A fair coin is flipped 100 times, yielding $H$ heads and $T$ tails. Which of the following is most likely?
>
> A) $H=50$
>
> B) $T>60$
>
> C) $48 \leq T$ and $48 \leq H$
>
> D) $51 \leq T \leq 55$
>
> E) $H\leq 5$ or $H \geq 95$

I eliminated A because it is a subset of C, and E because the tails of the distribution will be very very small.  I eliminate D because C also has five events which are overall more likely.  How do i compare $B$ and $C$?

I know how to solve this problem by brute force, but I am looking for a way to solve it in the 2 minutes 34 seconds allowed for each question on this test!

Comment: Given $48 T$s, you have 60 more tosses at play. It is more likely to get at least 12 $T$s than strictly  more than 12 $T$s. Hence, I think than more likely outcome is $C$.

Comment: If $T\leq 48$ and $H \leq 48$ then $100 = T+H \leq 96$. Thus C) cannot occur.

Comment: A is a subset of D, not C (since, as pointed out by @bryansis2010, the probability of C is zero). B and D are the ones you need to compare.

Comment: I had mistyped $C$, and now have fixed it.  It is the correct answer according to the answer key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the modification, the only reasonable choice is (C). It is pretty big, we can think of it as the probability of being within $0.4$ to $0.5$ standard deviation units of the mean.

For comparison with (D), note that the two intervals have the same length but (C) is "central." Recall that the binomial coefficients reach a maximum at the middle, and are symmetrical, reaching, in this case, a maximum at $50$.  So any interval of length $k$ symmetrical about the mean has greater probability than any non-symmetrical interval of the same length.

As to (B), it is more than $2$ standard deviation units up from the mean. The choices (A) and $(E)$ are ruled out for the reasons you described.

Comment: How do i know B is more than two standard deviations from the mean?  Is there a quick formula for binomial distribution problems like this?

Comment: Yes, and you need it in other GRE-type questions.  The variance is $np(1-p)$, $25$ in this case, so the standard deviation is $5$. For reasonable values of $p$, it is about $\sqrt{n}/2$.